# Error with !runaway command

Tags: windbg, sos, sosex

I am looking a dump file collected from production environment for high cpu usage. I ran **!threadpool** and **!runaway** command as follows

```
0:000> !ThreadPool
CPU utilization: 100%
Worker Thread: Total: 6 Running: 2 Idle: 4 MaxLimit: 32767 MinLimit: 4
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 8
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 8 Free: 3 MaxFree: 8 CurrentLimit: 8 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 4

0:000> !runaway
ERROR: !runaway: extension exception 0x80004002.
    "Unable to get thread times - dumps may not have time information"
```

I want to know what threads are consuming most cpu time but I cannot run !runaway command. Are there any other commands in sos, sosex or any other extension that could be helpful in this case?

Comment: how did you capture the dump? I would use ETW/WPA for analyzing for CPU usage: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis but use WPRUI.exe (under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start** after 1 minute, click on **save**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a tool that adds the necessary information to the dump.

In WinDbg, the `.dump` command has the `/mt` MiniOption, which

> Adds additional thread information to the minidump. This includes thread times, which can be displayed by using the **!runaway** extension or the **.ttime (Display Thread Times)** command when debugging the minidump.

(Emphasis: links in WinDbg)

The `t` option is included in the `a` option as well, so `.dump /ma` is fine as well.

To find out whether or not your dump has that information, use the undocumented command `.dumpdebug` like this:

```
.shell -ci ".dumpdebug" findstr "MiniDump"
```

If there is a line

```
1000 MiniDumpWithThreadInfo
```

the information is contained and you have a different issue. If it's not there, the time info is not available.

Most other tools I know do not provide such detailed settings, so it's more or less luck, whether this info is included or not.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I have tried what you have suggested and I am able to get `1000 MiniDumpWithThreadInfo` in the output. Can you suggest some basic commands to troubleshoot the possible causes for the failure of `!runaway` command.

Comment: @AjendraPrasad: could you get in contact with me via email and provide the affected crash dump for as, so I can analyze the issue? I never had such a case, so I don't exactly know what to do next. I'll need some time myself first.

Comment: thanks for your cooperation but the dump is provided with the agreement of confidentiality. However, I tried another Microsoft tool to analyze the dump  "Download Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2". It provides me top 5 time consuming threads. Thanks again